# Is there a way to get a path to the bit bucket like /dev/null in unix.?

Tags: java, file, io

I want to abandon redirect error from Process.
I also know the existence of NullWriter in apache.
However, Process only accepts File, doesnt it?

As far as I know, a special file (null device) like /dev/null has another path in Windows, for instance..

So my question is if and how can I get such path? 
Otherwise, should I set the one manually for each OS or platform?

My code is

```
File bitBucket = isUnix())? new File("/dev/null"): new File("NULL");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mpirun", "-np", 100, "mpi-tip").redirectError(bitBucket);
pb.start();
```

I want to change the 1st line
    File butBucket = getNullDevice(); // like this.

If only ProcessBuilder accpets Writer, I could use NullWriter though...

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. In the topic you ask for `get a path to the bit bucket` and in the descriptions you want a solution for `to abandon redirect error`. What you want to achieve? Redirect the error stream output (stderr) from the child process?

Comment: Redirection is my purpose and the reason why I want to ask how to get a path to the bit bucket.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth to explain what do you mean with `bit bucket`. Show a small snippet of code which shows your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The 'bit bucket' is meant to be null device like /dev/null or NUL or...  
My code is this
    File bitbucket = new File("/dev/null"); // !!here!! it will be NULL in windows instead, but Id like to do  File bitbucket = getNullDevice(); for example
    new ProcessBuilder("mpirun", "-np", String.valueOf(np), "mpi-tipsv") .redirectError(bitbucket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you still need to provide more information. I assume you want to suppress the error output from `mpirun`. By default the output to `stdout` and `stderr` of the started process is not merged to the JVMs output.

Find below an snippet for demonstration

**to_stderr.sh** - a helper script which print to `stdout` and `stderr`

```
#!/bin/bash
(>&2 echo "to stderr")
echo "to stdout"
```

verify the script

```
# supress output to stdout
./to_stderr.sh > /dev/null
to stderr

# supress output to stderr
./to_stderr.sh 2> /dev/null
to stdout
```

So now in Java

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./to_stderr.sh");
        pb.start();
    }
}
```

compile and run

```
javac Main.java && java Main
```

this would not output anything on the console, as long you don't redirect the error or output from the process.

So why you want/need to redirect to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Thank you for the examples. 
and yes, ... I just want to suppress that. Sorry confusing you.
Should I use a script to throw outputs from mpi executable as you suggest?
    #!bin/bash
    mpirun mpiexe >/dev/null

Comment: @kensuke1984 In my example the script was used only as replacement for your `mpirun` command. Take my example Java snippet and replace `new ProcessBuilder("./to_stderr.sh");` by `new ProcessBuilder("mpirun", "-np", 100, "mpi-tip");`. You shouldn't see the output to `stderr` from your `mpirun` execution.

Comment: I understand. I somehow misunderstand the default value of redirectError is INHERIT but it is PIPE... Thank  you for leading me. I am not sure how PIPE works but I will look for explanations. Thank you very much again.